# Loading sklearn model from S3 without providing authentication

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, scikit-learn, pickle

If a sklearn model is pickled and uploaded publicly to S3, is there a way to load it from there. Say I have a bucket called model and a pickle file in that bucket called truncated_svd.pkl. Is there a way that I can use pickle to load my truncated_svd.pkl file from S3 without having to provide authentication. The only reason I do not want to authenticate this is because this code needs to be publicly available.

Comment: you can still show it publicly and authenticate by binding your variables into your `.bash_profile` and then calling on them using `os.environ['blah']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **bucket policy** to your S3 bucket so that anyone could get access to your bucket using a **URL**.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

See below

[image: bucket policy location]

[image]

You can now use the [*requests*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module in order to do a GET request to that URL and unpicke your model.